# Changing the top margin in LaTeX for chapter name

Tags: margins, chapters

When a new chapter starts I want to decrease the margin between the top of the page and where it says Chapter X. So I have something like

Chapter X

Chapter Title

and I want to decrease the space between the beginning of the page and Chapter X

Comment: The linked question asks primarily to *remove* the space between the top margin and start of the chapter content. However, it should be fairly straight forward from any of the answers how it could be modified to *adjust* the default 50pt gap to suit your needs.